# Cannot take digits from string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use `Pattern` to taking digits from a string.

The string that contains my digits looks like:

```
{1,3}{4,5}...{6,7}
```

My output should be:

```
1 3
4 5
...
6 7
```

Code:

```
private static void products(final String products) {
    final String regex = "(\\{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\})+";


    final java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);

    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(products);
    if(!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong semantic of products!");
    }

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that a call to the above function doesn't print anything out. How would I fix this?

Comment: This regex "(\\{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\})+" is not working for finding digits in string.

Comment: @Andremoniy It doesn't work...

Comment: @vikingsteve "It doesn't work" is not really specific enough. Does it throw an error? Does it print the wrong output? Or what? And yes, I know, after testing it, that it's not printing out anything. But I shouldn't have had to test it to find this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
private static void products2(final String products) {
    final String regex = "\\{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\}";

    if (products.split(regex).length > 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong semantic of products!");
    }

    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(products);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

This one is probably less efficient (`String.split(...)`) yet possibly more elegant (separates validation from processing).

Comment: Why `products.split(regex).length > 0` **would** work - [`"Trailing empty strings are [therefore] not included in the resulting array."`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Can you please give an input example that then wouldn't work?

Comment: It **would** work (at least from what I can tell). I just posted that comment in case anyone is wondering **why** it works (because I did).

Comment: Ok. Wasn't sure what you meant there - can't see how single-argument split() "Splits this string around matches of the given regex" would ever return empty strings.

Comment: Well, `"abbdbe".split("b")` returns `{"a","","d","e"}` (which is "around" the `b`'s), so, naturally `"bbb".split("b")` should return `{"", "", "", ""}`, but they're all removed as a result of the above quote.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Weird that I didnt see that but still gave the better answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to take out the `+` at the end, since you want to extract them one at a time.

The whole thing is in brackets, this will be group 1, either make it a non-matching group (with `?:`) or start from 2. Removing the brackets won't work because of adding the `+` in the following regex (see code).

`matcher.matches` checks the whole string, which won't work with the regex without the `+`, you'll probably still need the original regex for this.

Also, using `matches` and then `find` on the same `Matcher` won't work, since `matches` will move the current position in the string, thus, if it matches, it will be at the end of the string. Thus `find` won't ever find anything, since there is no string left to search. You can use `reset` on the `Matcher` to reset its position, but this obviously won't solve the above problems.

Updated code:

```
private static void products(final String products) {
    final String regex = "(?:\\{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\})";

    // validation
    final Pattern pAll = Pattern.compile(regex + "+");

    if (!pAll.matcher(products).matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong semantic of products!");
    }

    // extraction
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(products);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/RsEiFH).

For anyone interested, here's a way of doing it in 1 pass: (`matches` goes through the whole string, thus resulting in 2 passes through the string)

```
private static void products(final String products) {
    final String regex = "\\{([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\\}";

    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(products);
    int lastEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (lastEnd != matcher.start())
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong semantic of products!");
        System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        lastEnd = matcher.end();
    }
    if (lastEnd != products.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong semantic of products!");
}
```

The only disadvantage is that it will print out all values prior to finding invalid data.

For example, `products("{1,3}{4,5}a{6,7}");` will print out:

```
1 3
4 5
```

prior to throwing the exception (because up until there the string is valid).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to split the string on "}", then go through the resulting array and extract the numbers. Each array element should match "\\{(\\d+),(\\d+)"